# Drag Drop List in Tkinter

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

```
from tkinter import *
import tkinter as tk
root = tk.Tk()

def add_many_songs():
    # Loop thru to fill list box
    for song in range(11):
        playlist_box.insert(END, song)
        
        
playlist_box =tk.Listbox(root,bg="black", fg="green", width=60, selectbackground="green", selectforeground='black',font = 20)
playlist_box.grid(row=0, column=0)

add_many_songs()

class DragDropListbox(tk.Listbox):
    """ A Tkinter listbox with drag'n'drop reordering of entries. """
    def __init__(self, master, **kw):
        kw['selectmode'] = tk.SINGLE
        tk.Listbox.__init__(self, master, kw)
        self.bind('<Button-1>', self.setCurrent)
        self.bind('<B1-Motion>', self.shiftSelection)
        self.curIndex = None

    def setCurrent(self, event):
        self.curIndex = self.nearest(event.y)

    def shiftSelection(self, event):
        i = self.nearest(event.y)
        if i < self.curIndex:
            x = self.get(i)
            self.delete(i)
            self.insert(i+1, x)
            self.curIndex = i
        elif i > self.curIndex:
            x = self.get(i)
            self.delete(i)
            self.insert(i-1, x)
            self.curIndex = i
```

##I found this code that does drag and drop features within tkinter list.  I got it to work with the example code.  However, I am not able to get it to work within the attached code.  I am still learning Python.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use the class `DragDropListbox` instead of `tk.Listbox` when creating `playlist_box`:

```py
import tkinter as tk

def add_many_songs():
    # Loop thru to fill list box
    for song in range(11):
        playlist_box.insert(tk.END, song)
        
        
class DragDropListbox(tk.Listbox):
    """ A Tkinter listbox with drag'n'drop reordering of entries. """
    def __init__(self, master, **kw):
        kw['selectmode'] = tk.SINGLE
        tk.Listbox.__init__(self, master, kw)
        self.bind('<Button-1>', self.setCurrent)
        self.bind('<B1-Motion>', self.shiftSelection)
        self.curIndex = None

    def setCurrent(self, event):
        self.curIndex = self.nearest(event.y)

    def shiftSelection(self, event):
        i = self.nearest(event.y)
        if i < self.curIndex:
            x = self.get(i)
            self.delete(i)
            self.insert(i+1, x)
            self.curIndex = i
        elif i > self.curIndex:
            x = self.get(i)
            self.delete(i)
            self.insert(i-1, x)
            self.curIndex = i

root = tk.Tk()

playlist_box = DragDropListbox(root,bg="black", fg="green", width=60, selectbackground="green", selectforeground='black',font = 20)
playlist_box.grid(row=0, column=0)

add_many_songs()

root.mainloop()
```

---

Note that it is not recommended to import tkinter like below:

```py
from tkinter import *
import tkinter as tk
```

Just use `import tkinter as tk`.